# Qt OSX system window close button state

Tags: macos, qt

Usually, when user modified document the native OSX application draw close button on system window as button with point.
Which is API in qt I should call for do the same?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Call the [`setWindowModified(true)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModified-prop) method for your window, and its content will be marked as modified. That means:

- In **OS X** the close button will be drawn with a dot inside;
- In **Windows** an asterisk sign will be printed in the window title (use the `[*]` placeholder).

Note that this method **does not** provide *"Really Quit?"*, *"Discard Changes?"*, *"Save the Changes?"* or similar dialogs. If you need to show such dialog before exit, you will have to write your own.